# Deployment error webapplication project netbeans and glass fish

Tags: java, netbeans

i created my first web application project, with NetBeans 8.0.2 on glassfish server 4.1
when i try to deploy it display the following output

Starting GlassFish Server 4.1
GlassFish Server 4.1 is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 54 seconds)

when i click on the link of the error it points to this line of code in the build-imp.xml

nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>

i tried the following:

- i made netbeans IDE run as administrator
- i played around with proxy settings still same error
- also when i try to clean and build my app this error occurs

Deleting directory C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build
C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1429: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

appreciate if u can tell me how to debug this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting

```
Unable to delete file C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Goto `C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\` directory and delete the `build` and `dist` folders manually.

After that come back to NetBeans and try to clean and build your project. Then run your project. This should deploy your web project.

Or else create an empty Web application project in NetBeans and try to run that project without modifying any contents of project.